# LNK2001 with Cmake static library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake

I am struggling to link to a static library created with CMake in another Visual C++ project. I am getting LNK2001 unresolved symbol errors for all the symbols in the library. Forgot to link with the library? I really don't think I have, as I have specified it as an absolute path and verified that if I change the name I get an error that it can't find the library - so it's definitely looking at it.

I used DUMPBIN to look at the symbol names and they seem different to what VC++ is looking for, e.g.

(in static library)

```
??0Matrix@NEWMAT@@QAE@HH@Z (public: __thiscall NEWMAT::Matrix::Matrix(int,int))
```

(unresolved symbol)

```
public: __cdecl NEWMAT::Matrix::Matrix(int,int)" (??0Matrix@NEWMAT@@QEAA@HH@Z)
```

note QAE vs QEAA in the decoration, also the library has __thiscall whereas the compiler is looking for __cdecl

It looks like the calling convention might be the issue, but why would it be different, and is there a compiler switch to make it consistent?

I have gone through the project properties and tried to make all compiler options the same but to no avail. Unfortunately I'm not a VC++ expert so it is probably something very simple, but anyone able to help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would take a look at a difference in the header files you deploy with the library and the header files you build the library with.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have apparently fixed this although I'm confused by the error I got. It seems the CMake library was targeting x86, not x64. I discovered this when I tried to link to a different library in the same group which then reported an error about inconsistent machine types. Having fixed CMake to do a x64 build I notice that the calling convention is now as expected and I have no unresolved symbols.

Just a bit unclear why I didn't get the machine type error on the first library but such is life.